# Majoration of integral in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis

we put
$$
I= \dfrac{1}{(4 \pi \delta_n \kappa)^{d/2}} \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \exp\left(\dfrac{-|y|^2}{4 \delta_n \kappa}\right) |y| \mathrm{d}y
$$
where $\kappa >0$ and $\delta_n= \dfrac{1}{2^n}, \ n \in \mathbb{N^{\star}}$.

My question is: how we can obtaine that $|I| \leq C_{\kappa,\delta_n} \leq C'_{\kappa} \delta_n$?

where $C_{\kappa,\delta_n}$ is constant dependent of $\kappa$ and $\delta_n$ and $C'_{\kappa}$ constant depend only on $\kappa$.
Kind regards

Comment: What makes you believe that an estimate of this form holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your bound does not hold but a bound of the form $|I| ≤ C_κ \delta_n^{1/2}$ (and actually you have even better an equality). This can be obtained by a simple change of variable. Taking $y = \sqrt{\lambda}\, x$ gives
$$
\frac{1}{(\lambda\pi)^{d/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{-|y|^2/\lambda}\,|y|\,\mathrm{d}y = \frac{\lambda^{\frac{d+1}{2}}}{(\lambda\pi)^{d/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{-|x|^2}\,|x|\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{C_d}{\pi^{d/2}} \lambda^{1/2},
$$
where $C_d = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{-|x|^2}\,|x|\,\mathrm{d}x$ (which is finite, depends only on $d$ and can be computed explicitly in terms of the Gamma function). In your case, $λ = 4\delta_n\kappa$, which gives you
$$
I = \left(\frac{2\,C_d}{\pi^{d/2}} \kappa^{1/2}\right) \delta_n^{1/2}.
$$

Comment: Please, we have $$
I= \dfrac{1}{(4 \pi \delta_n \kappa)^{d/2}} \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \exp\left(\dfrac{-|y|^2}{4 \delta_n \kappa}\right) |y|^2 \mathrm{d}y= C \kappa \delta
$$? You confirm please

Comment: Yes, of course, by the same method (this changes $\lambda^\frac{d+1}{2}$ by $\lambda^\frac{d+2}{2}$ in my first equation, which gives
$$
I = \left(\frac{4\,C_d}{\pi^{d/2}} \kappa\right) \delta
$$
with $C_d = ∫ e^{-|x|^2} |x|^2\,\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: Thank you so much